# Prolog http get request with request headers

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I trying to do a http get request with request headers with prolog but I can't find out how to do it exacly.

Here's an example how to do it in Python:

```
response = unirest.get("https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=3",
headers={
"X-Mashape-Key": "mykey",
"Accept": "application/json"
}
```

The response of this request is in Json and looks like:

```
{
"player_cards": {
"1": [
  "Jh",
  "4c"
],
"2": [
  "3s",
  "Js"
],
"3": [
  "3d",
  "5c"
],
"4": [
  "Kh",
  "Qs"
]
},
"showdown": [
"Ks",
"6h",
"4s",
"Ac",
"9h"
],
"winning_hands": {
"1": [
  "4c",
  "4s",
  "Ac",
  "Ks",
  "Jh"
],
"2": [
  "Ac",
  "Ks",
  "Js",
  "9h",
  "6h"
],
"3": [
  "Ac",
  "Ks",
  "9h",
  "6h",
  "5c"
],
"4": [
  "Kh",
  "Ks",
  "Ac",
  "Qs",
  "9h"
]
},
"winners": [
4
]
}
```

My prolog code

```
poker(Players) :-
format(atom(HREF),'https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=~s',[Players]),
http_get(HREF,Json,[]),
```

How to specify the http get request headers here and how can I store and use the Json result? The function has to print the Json result, I know this can be done by writeln().

Answer (score 3):

I you want to specify HTTP request headers I would advise using `http_open/3` i.o. `http_get/3`. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(http/http_open)).
:- use_module(library(http/json)).

poker(Dict):-
  setup_call_cleanup(
    http_open('https://poker.p.mashape.com/index.php?players=3', In, [request_header('Accept'='application/json')]),
    json_read_dict(In, Dict),
    close(In)
  ).
```

Notice my use of `setup_call_cleanup/3`. This ensures that the stream gets closed even if the code in the middle fails or throws an exception.

`json_read_dict/2` returns a [SWI7 dictionary](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts). You need SWI-Prolog version 7 for this! Preferably the latest commit from [the development branch](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel).

It seems that the URI you are using requires SSL authentication. I believe it is possible to get this working in SWI-Prolog as well, but I could not find an example of how to do this. See [my question to the SWI-Prolog mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swi-prolog/o-bNvYxgqOA) on this.

Comment: Thanks Wouter for your code sample. I don't see the X-Mashape-Key specified as a request header in your sample, I think this is needed to get the Json response. I will look into the SWI7 dictionary, I'm using version 7. Also thanks for opening a ticket about the SSL authentication, looking forward for an answer on that question.

Comment: Just saw the answer on the ticket about SSL authentication, the SSL certificate looks okay, maybe the error is because the mashape key isn't specified in the request header?